# Hazelcast: notify when a cluster node dies

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast

I am quite a newbie to Hazelcast.
I'm building a cluster where different nodes take in charge different activities.
When a node dies, I'd like other nodes to notice, so they can reassign the dead node's activities among themselves. Is this possible?
I have already made some research for this, but I couldn't find anything useful. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways here, probably the simplest for what you describe is http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MembershipListener.html

However, you don't really want nodes dying in the first place, that's probably worth resolving.

Plus, it sounds like you're trying to manage workload placement yourself, simpler to let Hazelcast do it for you -- with for example with semaphores.

Comment: Wow, thank you, this might definitely be the solution I was looking for!
Thank you for your advices too. 
I don't want members to die: I was looking for a way to handle the worst case scenario :) 
I am using IMap.Lock objects so that nodes can lock the activities to execute. I was worried of what could happen in case of a node crashing: its activity would remain unassigned. With MembershipLIsteners, however, I can make the other nodes try to lock it again, so the fastest node (which is probably the less busy) will perform it.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are talking activities to execute, then http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.5/manual/html-single/index.html#durable-executor-service is possible also relevant