# Using Hazelcast, how can i create event or catch if member is shutdown and print message?

Tags: hazelcast

This is my source,how can i print message if some of the members is shut down for some reason?I think i can some event or some kind of action listener but how...

```
import com.hazelcast.core.*; 
import com.hazelcast.config.*;

import java.util.Map;


/**  *  * @author alvel  */ public class ShutDown {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config cfg = new Config();
        HazelcastInstance memberOne = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
         HazelcastInstance memberTwo = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
        Map<Integer, String> customerMap = memberOne.getMap("customers");
        customerMap.put(1, "google");
        customerMap.put(2, "apple");
        customerMap.put(3, "yahoo");
        customerMap.put(4, "microsoft");

        System.out.println("Hazelcast Nodes in this cluster"+Hazelcast.getAllHazelcastInstances().size());

        memberOne.shutdown();

         System.out.println("Hazelcast Nodes in this cluster After shutdown"+Hazelcast.getAllHazelcastInstances().size());

         Map<Integer, String> customerRestored = memberTwo.getMap("customers");
        for(String val:customerRestored.values()){
            System.out.println("-"+val);
        }

     } }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153963/hazelcast-notify-when-a-cluster-node-dies/46156011. A `MembershipListener` will do it

Comment: can you help me with implementation

Comment: There's an example here - http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.5/manual/html-single/index.html#listening-for-member-events . Create a new class implementing `MembershipListener`, and register it so that Hazelcast knows to send it those type of events -- in your code, something like `memberOne.getCluster().addMembershipListener(new ShutDownMembershipListener());`

Comment: @NeilStevenson it doesn't work,i overide given methods but after that,can you give me example,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it adds a few lines into your code and a new class

```
public class ShutDown {

static {
    // ONLY TEMPORARY
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "none");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Config cfg = new Config();
   HazelcastInstance memberOne = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
   //ADDED TO MEMBER ONE
   memberOne.getCluster().addMembershipListener(new ShutDownMembershipListener());
    HazelcastInstance memberTwo = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
   //ADDED TO MEMBER TWO
   memberTwo.getCluster().addMembershipListener(new ShutDownMembershipListener());
   Map<Integer, String> customerMap = memberOne.getMap("customers");
   customerMap.put(1, "google");
   customerMap.put(2, "apple");
   customerMap.put(3, "yahoo");
   customerMap.put(4, "microsoft");

   System.out.println("Hazelcast Nodes in this cluster"+Hazelcast.getAllHazelcastInstances().size());

   memberOne.shutdown();

    System.out.println("Hazelcast Nodes in this cluster After shutdown"+Hazelcast.getAllHazelcastInstances().size());

    Map<Integer, String> customerRestored = memberTwo.getMap("customers");
   for(String val:customerRestored.values()){
       System.out.println("-"+val);
   }

} 

static class ShutDownMembershipListener implements MembershipListener {

    @Override
    public void memberAdded(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
        System.out.println(this + membershipEvent.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void memberAttributeChanged(MemberAttributeEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void memberRemoved(MembershipEvent membershipEvent) {
        System.out.println(this + membershipEvent.toString());
    }
}
}
```

The line `System.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "none")` is just for testing to make it simpler to see what is happening.